# Using parameters in a script

Tags: bash, shell, shell-script, arguments

I usually use the find command to automatically copy certain multimedia files from directory A to directory B. I use the following command:

```
for f in `find ./ -name "*.mkv" -mtime -24h`; do cp $f rename/ ; done
```

This totally does what I want, but now that I have transferred the command into an executable script (let's call it `mmcopy`, it works perfectly) I wonder whether I could improve the script to do the following:

When I type `mmcopy` on the command line, I would like to parse two operators/variables to the script, namely a variable of the file extension and a variable to the mtime operator, so I can specify which kind of files should be copied and how old these files may be.

E.g.: I want to automatically copy (all) `.jpg` files in a directory that are newer than 3 days, the commandline should look like `mmcopy jpg -3d`

How would I have to change my script in order to be able to so?

Comment: If you call your script with `mmcopy jpg -3d` then you can use the variables `$1` and `$2` in your script, which will expand to `jpg` and `-3d` respectively. These variables are called positional parameters.

Answer (score 2):

First, your current script breaks on file names containing whitespace and other special characters. It's very easy to fix this: always use double quotes around variable substitutions, and use `-exec` instead of parsing the output of `find`. See [Why does my shell script choke on whitespace or other special characters?](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/131766/why-does-my-shell-script-choke-on-whitespace-or-other-special-characters) for more information.

```
find . -name "*.mkv" -mtime -24h -exec cp {} rename/ \;
```

Arguments passed to your script are available in the special parameters `$1`, `$2`, etc. Here's a script that copies files whose extension is the first parameter to the script and whose timestamp comparison is given by the second parameter.

```
#!/bin/sh
find . -name "*.$1" -mtime "$2" -exec cp {} rename/ \;
```

If you want to assume default values if the arguments are missing, you can use the [`${…:-…}` parameter expansion construct](http://www.gnu.org/software/bash/manual/bash.html#Shell-Parameter-Expansion).

```
#!/bin/sh
find . -name "*.${1:-mkv}" -mtime "${2:--1d}" -exec cp {} rename/ \;
```

I recommend replacing `cp` by `cp -p` or `rsync -a`. `cp -p` preserves the timestamp on the file, which makes it easier to tell when you've already copied a file. `rsync -a` additionally doesn't copy the file if it's already been copied (unless the original file has a different timestamp or size).

Comment: Thank you so much! I even almost understand the concept :-)